# How to solve a max CSP with a set of linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, computer-science, linear-programming, constraints, satisfiability

Suppose there is a set of $n$ linear constraints $\{a_i^Tx+b_i\le 0\}_{i=1}^n$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $b_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. How can I find $x^*$ that maximizes $\vert \{i\in [n]\mid a_i^Tx^*+b_i\le 0\}\vert$? Is this problem solvable or can be approximated  within polynomial time?

Some reference materials would also be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *maximum cardinality feasible subsystem problem* is NP-hard:
Chakravarti N., Some Results Concerning Post-Infeasibility Analysis,
European Journal of Operational Research, Vol. 73 (1994), pp. 139-
143.

You might also search for the equivalent *minimum cardinality IIS set cover problem*.

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable indicate whether constraint $i$ is satisfied. The problem is to maximize $\sum_i z_i$ subject to linear (big-M) constraints $$a_i^T x+b_i\le M_i(1-z_i) \quad \text{for all $i$}.$$ Here, $M_i$ is a (small) constant upper bound on the LHS when $z_i=0$.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is of course solvable by the MILP formulation. But the MILP problem is generally NP-complete. So I still want to know if this problem is as hard as 
 NP-complete problems so that I have to adopt a MILP approach?